# Webkit border radius sometimes take effect

Tags: webkit, css

This issue is about the CSS3 border-radius property (http://www.css3.info/border-radius-apple-vs-mozilla/)

An example of this problem is here:

http://jamtodaycdn.appspot.com/bin/rounded.html

In this URL, I have rounded divs that appear to be rounded in FF3, but on Safari and Chrome the rounded corners are not there.

The style is as follows:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:2px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:92px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:92px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 92px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 92px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
```

I'm fairly sure that this CSS is formatted correctly, so I'm clueless as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the 92px radia.  It looks like the maximum radius that the 20-pixel-high div can handle is 18px.  It's not necessarily obvious what a 92 pixel radius means in that case.  However, you can specify both an X and Y radius using something like this:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 92px 18px;
```

(side note, you shouldn't use the same ID for multiple HTML elements.  You should use class instead, and adjust your CSS selector so it says .round instead of #round.)

Comment: Good point about the ID. This was something I hacked up in a few seconds, but that's always good advice.

Comment: The maximum radius part makes sense, but the buggish part of this behavior is that if it can't render the border as specified, it doesn't round the border at all, whereas Mozilla renders the border as much as it can.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone referring to this for help with rounded corners, I agree with Jacob's answer regarding Webkit, but the question also mentioned Chrome not working. Chrome uses standard CSS3 rounded corners which are exactly like Webkit's, but without the preceding '-webkit-' on the rule. These are as follows:

```
border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
```

To take into account Firefox, Webkit and Chrome, you'd need to do something like this:

```
-moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
border-top-right-radius:3px;
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
```

The third set of rules are CSS3 rules and are supported by Chrome. This is a good way to also get rounded corners in  IE using something like CSS3Pie: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to apply a border or border-width property as well as the various border-radius   properties?

Also, I've noticed Safari dropping the radius above certain radius values - try reducing the pixel values & see what happens.

Comment: Regarding paragraph one, no, you don't need to specify "border" or "border-width" properties in order to use "border-radius" property.

Answer (score 1):

simple type just use:

`border-radius:92px 92px 2px 2px;`

where:

`border-radius:top right bottom left;`